# .sh add html5 template to created file

Tags: javascript, html, macos, shell, sh

I am in the process of creating a shell script .sh.

I now need to create a html file and add the html of a whole html5 template and same it.

So...

```
sh myshfile.sh

touch index.html
```

...Add the html of a html5 template

For example...create a html file and add this:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

...via a shell script.

How do I do this?

Comment: Well if you have your template saved somewhere you could always copy it, or you could echo the contents and cat to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the following methods.

If the content of the template is stored in a file,

```
cat template.html > index.html
```

If the content is to be stored in the script itself then,

```
echo "<html><h1>This is a test</h1></html>" > index.html
```

Don't forget to escape the quotes with `\"`